# How to select Available from this text in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

How to select *`Available`* from this text in JavaScript, as how to select all the elements after 4th `,` till the end of line. Either in JavaScript or regex. The search should not go on next line,

```
str = ertyuiiokjhv,TATA-SBC,A4X-PLUTO-Verifications + XLAM -OP,Available,0099 // String

var status = str.substring(4, str.indexOf(","));
```

This is not working.

Comment: Could you explain exactly what you need to do? Need little bit clarity on your question

Comment: I need to get all the data after 4th special character as (,) in this case. Any data between 4th (,) and 5th (,) i want to fetch in console.log or alert

Comment: I want to fetch complete string in this case

Answer (score 1):

By doing like this you will get each word in seperate fields in an array

Then you could get the desired values based on the index

```
var str="ertyuiiokjhv,TATA-SBC,A4X-PLUTO-Verifications + XLAM -OP,Available,0099" // String

var strings=str.split(",");
console.log(strings[4]);
```

Correct me if my idea is different

the above code will give u the result as "0099"

Answer (score 1):

```
const str = 'ertyuiiokjhv,TATA-SBC,A4X-PLUTO-Verifications + XLAM -OP,Available,0099';

const arr = str.split(',');

const av = arr[arr.indexOf('Available')]; // = 'Available'
```

---

**Updated** according to the comment :

> I need to get all the data after 4th special character as (,) in this case. Any data between 4th (,) and 5th (,) i want to fetch in console.log or alert

You can get subset of string after nth ',' (n is zero based)

```
const str = 'ertyuiiokjhv,TATA-SBC,A4X-PLUTO-Verifications + XLAM -OP,Available,0099';

const arr = str.split(',');

// in this case n = 3
arr.filter((string,i) => i > 3 && string).join(',') // = '0099'
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use the `split` function and then get the forth token (i.e., index `3`), like this:

```
token1 = str.split(',')[3]; // Available
```

If you want to get the number just after *`Available`*, you can get it using the fifth token, like this

```
token2 = str.split(',')[4]; // 0099
```

Hope it helps.